# Adding additional OPTION clause to raw T-SQL select with if condition

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a `SELECT` for two different situations. Both `SELECT`s are almost identical except a few lines which I would like to add with if condition. However, I constantly get an error. Is it possible to use either `IF` or `CASE` syntax in order to achieve the desired result?

I have:

```sql
DECLARE @isQuarter varchar(5) = true

SELECT [result] = res.Result
FROM Custom_results cr
WHERE cr.index = 12
IF @isQuarter = true
BEGIN
    OPTION(RECOMPILE);
END
```

I get this error:

> [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

If I use `CASE WHEN THEN` instead of `IF`, I get another error:

> [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: You can't use a `IF` in the middle of a statement, it's a logical flow operator. `CASE` on the other hand is an expression that returns a scalar value; it's *not* a logical flow operator. What you have above doesn't have sense though. Why do you want to regenerate the query plan when `@isQuarter` has the value `true`?

Comment: Also `DECLARE @isQuarter varchar(5) = true` is going to error. You either want `@isQuarter` to be a bit and `true` should `1`, or your value `true` should be a literal `varchar` .

Comment: Well, I have a query that I'd like to use in two different situations with small changes in it. I thought it would be much cleaner to reuse the same query with an additional 'OPTION' clause instead of writing a completely new query and @isQuarter is an external parameter, which is passed to the function which creates this query

Comment: I think we're missing something here, the above query isn't a catch-all/kitchen sink query, so it'll have no benefit from an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't place here the whole query since it's very long. I tried to simplify it since my main question is if it's possible to reuse most part of the query for two different situations

Comment: Show us what you *actually* have. As I stated, the above doesn't make any sense. Though, if you have a catch-all/kitchen sink query, the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` should *always* be there, not added dynamically. Sometimes adding it dynamically would completely ruin the point of it being there.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a read of [Catch-All Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: Short Answer: NO. You can use conditional expressions (i.e. `CASE WHEN`) is some parts of the query such as `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` but not in [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15).